# NiFi 1.3.X Secure Cluster Setup Issue: HTTPS Wrong Hostname wrong should be: <my.ip.address>

Tags: apache-nifi

I have followed these articles (among others) to set up the secure cluster:

[Apache NiFi 1.0.0 - Authorization and Multi-Tenancy](http://bryanbende.com/development/2016/08/17/apache-nifi-1-0-0-authorization-and-multi-tenancy)

But bellow error I have attached

[image: Error of nifi secure cluster]

`nifi.properties`

```py
# Site to Site properties 
nifi.remote.input.host=nifibizruntime.com 
nifi.remote.input.secure=true 
nifi.remote.input.socket.port=10443 
nifi.remote.input.http.enabled=true 
nifi.remote.input.http.transaction.ttl=30 sec 
# web properties 
nifi.web.war.directory=./lib 
nifi.web.http.host= 
nifi.web.http.port= 
nifi.web.http.network.interface.default= 
nifi.web.https.host=nifibizruntime.com 
nifi.web.https.port=9443 
nifi.web.https.network.interface.default= 
nifi.web.jetty.working.directory=./work/jetty 
nifi.web.jetty.threads=200
```

The error in `nifi-app.log` file:

```py
com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: java.io.IOException: HTTPS hostname wrong: should be <XXX.XXX.1.XX> 
    at com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandl‌​er.handle(URLConnect‌​ionClientHandler.jav‌​a:155) 
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.handle(Client.java:652)
    ...
```

Comment: could you provide the parameters `nifi.remote.*` and `nifi.web.*` from the `nifi.properties` ?

Comment: Hello @daggett 
# Site to Site properties
nifi.remote.input.host=nifibizruntime.com
nifi.remote.input.secure=true
nifi.remote.input.socket.port=10443
nifi.remote.input.http.enabled=true
nifi.remote.input.http.transaction.ttl=30 sec
# web properties #
nifi.web.war.directory=./lib
nifi.web.http.host=
nifi.web.http.port=
nifi.web.http.network.interface.default=
nifi.web.https.host=nifibizruntime.com
nifi.web.https.port=9443
nifi.web.https.network.interface.default=
nifi.web.jetty.working.directory=./work/jetty
nifi.web.jetty.threads=200

Comment: `nifibizruntiem.com` - is it a valid hostname that server could resolve to ip address?

Comment: @daggett yes its valid hostname .. i have cross verified (i have configured local lab) where with network it reach

Comment: Even i have Provided  IP address.  but getting same error

Comment: please put properties from comment into the question. also find the full error in the `nifi-app.log` and add to your question. if the nifi inside the virtual machine check how it resolves the hostname from inside. also provide the lines with ip addresses from log file after the line `NiFi has started.` are you trying the same ip address as in error?

Comment: Yes am providing  the same ip address as in error 
here nifi.app.log
om.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: java.io.IOException: HTTPS hostname wrong:  should be <XXX.XXX.1.XX>
 at com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler.handle(URLConnectionClientHandler.java:155)
 at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.handle(Client.java:652)

Comment: seems something wrong with your certificate in keystore and/or in truststore. if you connecting your server by hostname the certificate must be provided for the hostname. if you use a keytool you can specify alternative host or ip for your certificate by using `-ext SAN=dns:myhostname,ip:1.2.3.4`

Comment: @daggett thanks for the solution yes it sloved :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems something wrong with your certificate in keystore and/or in truststore.

if you connecting your server by `hostname` the certificate must be provided for the `hostname`.

if you use a [`java keytool`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/keytool.html) to generate primary certificate, you can specify alternative host or ip for your certificate by using `-ext SAN=dns:myhostname,ip:1.2.3.4` parameter